# Create AWS S3 presigned URL with MD5 hash using PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I've been unable to construct an S3 presigned URL containing a MD5 hash.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client( ... );
$md5Hash = "YmEwMWVmNzE5MjI3YzdjNmI0ZjYzNGMxZWI1MmY1Y2U=";
$cmd = $s3->getCommand('PutObject', [
                            'Bucket' => $bucket,
                            'Key'    => $key,
                            'Content-MD5' => $md5Hash,
                            'ContentType' => $contentType,
                            'Body'        => ''    
                        ]);

$request = $s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+5 minutes');
$presignedUrl = (string)$request->getUri();
```

The resulting presignedURL looks something like:

http://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/{bucket}/{key}?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWC7FFD2T3NCEUNQ%2F20170503%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170503T215723Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3000&X-Amz-Signature=ca61d80dcfee351e7ee8440a47c5007f1bc905ddc8229077abddab9c39412dc7

When I add the Content-MD5 hash to my PUT request, I get back an error indicating the MD5 header wasn't signed:

AccessDenied - There were headers present in the request which were not signed
HeadersNotSigned - content-md5

Any help appreciated!